# Calculating values from a while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I need to use data entered into my while loop to calculate a sum and a max value. I'm confused as to how I can take the user input for each "day" I have stored as "weathervalue" and use it in a formula to outside the loop. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
double weatherdays;
double weathervalue;
double counter;
double day;

cout << "Enter the number of days for which you have weather data - ";
cin >> weatherdays;

counter = 1;
day = 1;

while (counter <= weatherdays)
{
    counter++;

    cout << "What is the rainfall for day " << day << endl;
    cin >> weathervalue;

    cout << "What is the max temp for day " << day << endl;
    cin >> weathervalue;

    day = day + 1;
}

weathervalue = //formula for sum of rainfall values entered in while loop

cout << "The total rainfall is " << weathervalue << endl;

weathervalue = //formula for max temp values entered in while loop

cout << "The max temperature is " << weathervalue << endl;
```

Comment: Just use a double inside the while body to store the current value read from stdin and add it to some accumulator, e.g. weathervalue_sum. For the max, keep your current maximum in a variable and replace it when the value is greater than it.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you want user to input each day, you need to do cin>> for each day in the while loop until your condition is satisfied. Please rewrite your question and post back.

Comment: The question is very clear. She/he wants to get sum and max of two data series, and can't think about a way to do that.

Comment: @Nebulan you should also check what user gave as input, sometimes users do not behave as you expect them to e.g. faceroll on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do **not** need arrays to do this task. Two variables representing the current state would do:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int weatherdays;
    int day = 0;
    double rainfall;
    double temperature;

    double sumRainfall = 0.0;
    double maxTemperature = 0.0;

    cout << "Enter the number of days for which you have weather data - ";
    cin >> weatherdays;

    while (weatherdays--)
    {
        ++day;

        cout << "What is the rainfall for day " << day << endl;
        cin >> rainfall;
        sumRainfall += rainfall;

        cout << "What is the max temp for day " << day << endl;
        cin >> temperature;
        if(temperature > maxTemperature)
        {
            maxTemperature = temperature;
        }
    }

    cout << "The total rainfall is " << sumRainfall << endl;

    cout << "The max temperature is " << maxTemperature << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can also use `std` algorithms present in `<algorithm>`, but that would be just a cakewalk then!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to store *all* the entered values?

Use a colle tion, such as `vector`.

```
cin >> wearhervalue;
vals.push_back (weathervalue);
```

Comment: true. A simply array should do the job. Also, `vals` need to be a stack of queue type of thingy which, he/she might have no experience in....sounds like a year 1 uni project to me.

Comment: You don't even need an array

Comment: A bare C array would have a maximum size.  Using vector as container of first resort is how someone should learn.  But, “all C++ books are now obsolete” so who knows how it's being taught??